# Where the property key name for the chromedriver has been determined and where it is getting utilized in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We usually set the system property for the chromedriver exe using the below code

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",path of the chromedriver.exe)

1. How the property key name is determined as "webdriver.chrome.driver"?
2. Where the property is utilized in Webdriver wire protocol(Any particular class file for reference)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi i have write utils class for that 

You can open browser/navigate url/close browser and etc 


    package utils;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TestApp {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private static TestApp myObj;
    // public static WebDriver driver;
    utils.PropertyFileReader property = new PropertyFileReader();

    public static TestApp getInstance() {
        if (myObj == null) {
            myObj = new TestApp();
            return myObj;
        } else {
            return myObj;
        }
    }

    //get the selenium driver
    public WebDriver getDriver()
    {
        return driver;
    }

    //when selenium opens the browsers it will automatically set the web driver
    private void setDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public static void setMyObj(TestApp myObj) {
        TestApp.myObj = myObj;
    }

    public void openBrowser() {
        //String chromeDriverPath = property.getProperty("config", "chrome.driver.path");
        //String chromeDriverPath = property.getProperty("config", getChromeDriverFilePath());
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", getChromeDriverFilePath());
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void navigateToURL() {
        String url =property.getProperty("config","url");
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public void closeBrowser()
    {
        driver.quit();
    }

    public WebElement waitForElement(By locator, int timeout)
    {
        WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(TestApp.getInstance().getDriver(), timeout).until
                 (ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
        return element;
    }

    private String getChromeDriverFilePath()
    {
        // checking resources file for chrome driver in side main resources
        URL res = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("chromedriver.exe");
        File file = null;
        try {
            file = Paths.get(res.toURI()).toFile();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}

    enter code here
```

Comment: you can read those url from config file on project (when you modularize selenium automation framework its usefull)

Comment: Actually, my query is how we are arriving to the conclusion that this is the property name  "webdriver.chrome.driver" ?